# TeXLive package details

Tags: miktex, texlive

MikTeX has a nice searchable list of packages at [miktex.org/packages](https://miktex.org/packages/) and, the best part, if you click on a package
you get [this nice overview](https://miktex.org/packages/handin) that includes the version number and a date.

For TeXLive all I can find is a long list in an svn trunk. *The following link takes a while to load:* [TeXLive SVN trunk link](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/).

For the package [this](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/) is the best overview I can find.

My question is: is there anything like the [detailed package info at MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/packages/handin)  for TeXLive?

---

Why would I want this?
I like to track my own packages and also check the status of other packages at TeXLive, not only on CTAN.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

well I don't know miktex but `tlmgr` will let you browse the texlive package database, for example on my system `tlmgr info pgf` produces:

```
$ tlmgr info pgf
package:     pgf
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Create PostScript and PDF graphics in TeX
longdesc:    PGF is a macro package for creating graphics. It is platform- and format-independent and works together with the most important TeX backend drivers, including pdfTeX and dvips. It comes with a user-friendly syntax layer called TikZ. Its usage is similar to pstricks and the standard picture environment. PGF works with plain (pdf-)TeX, (pdf-)LaTeX, and ConTeXt. Unlike pstricks, it can produce either PostScript or PDF output.
installed:   Yes
revision:    44231
sizes:       src: 369k, doc: 14009k, run: 5261k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 3.0.1a
cat-date:    2018-02-21 05:37:59 +0100
cat-license: lppl1.3gpl2
cat-topics:  pgf-tikz graphics-in-tex
collection:  collection-pictures
```